Formatting JSON for Python - need to remove \"
I've got some JSON that looks like this:
{"name": "John",
 "description": "I'm just \"A BOY\" okay? He said \"Hello, World!\" to everyone.",
 "remark": "\"This is a test\" he mentioned."}

And the \" instances are breaking json.loads().
import json

json_string = '''{"name": "John",
"description": "I'm just \"A BOY\" okay? He said \"Hello, World!\" to everyone.",
"remark": "\"This is a test\" he mentioned."}'''
data = json.loads(json_string)

print(data)

raises:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 27 (char 43)
I feel like I've tried every regex under the sun to target these instances (but leave all the other double quotes, not preceded by a backslash) and replace them with an empty string (functionally just strip them). If anyone has tips I'd appreciate it.
My implementation right now is something like:
import re

# Define a regular expression pattern to match \" within a string
pattern = r'\\"'

# Use re.sub to replace all occurrences of the pattern with an empty string
cleaned_string = re.sub(pattern, '', json_string)

print(cleaned_string)

But when i run this in a repl, nothing changes.
For reference, I'd just like the output to be:
{"name": "John",
 "description": "I'm just A BOY okay? He said Hello, World! to everyone.",
 "remark": "This is a test he mentioned."}

Edit: for clarity this is just an example of the nature of the input data i'm working with, its coming from AWS Cloudwatch logs so I don't have an easy way to manipulate the input before dragging it into Python. For example, part of the payload is something like
"\"Girl Let's Talk\" Virtual 90s Kickback"

In context:
{"search_ads": [ {"event_id": "4838383", "ad_id": "1112", "budget_amount": 5.0, "currency": "USD", "marketplace": "Online_US", "score": 18.205433, "p_click": 0.0, "p_order": 0.0, "goal": 2, "category_id": 113, "subcategory_id": 13999, "format": null, "is_paid": false, "online_event": true, "event_start_date": "2024-06-28T00:00:00Z", "latitude": null, "longitude": null, "name": "\"Girl Let's Talk\" Virtual 90s Kickback", "vip_status": false, "is_participant": true}]}

so the \" characters are really the only problem - if I copy all that input into VS Code and just search for/delete that pattern, json.loads() works great as is.
As one commenter mentioned, i think what im looking for is a regex that will match and strip the pattern \" but ive had no luck with that so far! Ive only been able to strip either the \s, which leaves me with double quotes that break json.loads() (expecting delimiter aka thinks this is another JSON key/val pair) or stripping all the double-quotes, which of course completely breaks the same.

You need to escape the backslashes when you define json_string. If you print(json_string) you'll see your intended backslashes are missing. Maybe it's just an error in the example but it's not representative as written.

What is the error message? That's not valid JSON (it would need to be within {} even if the escapes are working). And in this example, you are dealing with the escape rules of a python string literal. print(json_string) and you'll see that the backslashes aren't there. Where did this JSON string come from? Can you verify the exact string and not some sort of an escaped display of the string? Maybe write it to a file and view with a text editor?

For instance, if I write exactly {"description":"I'm just \"A BOY\" okay?"} to a file and read it with print(json.load(open("test.json"))["description"]), I get a string: I'm just "A BOY" okay?. I could use a regex to strip the literal \" before the json.load or remove " from values after the load.

The is no backslash in your data. There is just a backslash with a quotation mark representing an escaped quotation mark. The quotation marks is escaped because it is not allowed by the syntax on its own at this place.

No need to use a regular expression, just a simple json_string.replace(r'\"', '') would work fine.

I just edited but it wouldn't let me leave an edit summary so I'm putting it in a comment instead for now: Integrate edit fully. Remove solution: solutions go in answers, not in the question. Remove redundant, malformed data.

I forgot to say before, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips for future questions, like making a [mre] before posting.

You do not need to remove \". It's part of the data.*
What you're having a problem with is Python's interpretation of string literals. The sequence \" is an escape sequence that turns into just ".
>>> '\"'
'"'

This can be solved with a raw string (r prefix).
import json

json_string = r'''
{"name": "John",
 "description": "I'm just \"A BOY\" okay? He said \"Hello, World!\" to everyone.",
 "remark": "\"This is a test\" he mentioned."}
'''

data = json.loads(json_string)

print(data['description'])

Output:
I'm just "A BOY" okay? He said "Hello, World!" to everyone.


See also: How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?

However, you might prefer to put the JSON in a separate file and use json.load(), to avoid having to muck around with string literals at all.

* To be more precise, it's part of the JSON. In a JSON string, \" represents ", which is the raw data.

Your JSON-snippet seems valid but you need to write
json_string = '''
"name": "John",
"description": "I'm just \\"A BOY\\" okay? He said \\"Hello, World!\\" to everyone.",
"remark": "\\"This is a test\\" he mentioned."
'''

in your code. It is probably less confusing if you are loading it from file avoiding the double backslash.
Also pattern = r'\\"' is too much. Write pattern = r'\"' or pattern = '\\"'.
